# What is this green and yellow vegetable which looks like a star from above?

Tags: identification, vegetables, squash, gourds

We found this vegetable, apparently a gourd of some sort, growing at a farm in Michigan, but we're not sure which particular species it could be. It seems to most closely resemble an acorn squash, but the star-shaped spike pattern on the outside does not appear to match. Other types of squash, such as butternut, are too different in color scheme and shape.

Does anyone know what this unidentified vegetable could be?

[image: Photo of unidentified gourd 1][image: Photo of unidentified gourd 2]

Comment: Looks like some kind of gourd to me.

Comment: Since gourds hybridize easily it seems unlikely you'll get a clear identification.  However here are seeds to grow something perhaps similar:  https://www.reneesgarden.com/products/gourd-specialty-wings-and-warts.  Also try googling "winged gourds".

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be related the the squash in some way. It may be a gourd because of its odd shape and the two unrelated colors.